# How to execute a function from a shell-script from C

Tags: c, bash, shell

I have a user supplied script like

```
#!/bin/sh

some_function () {
    touch some_file
}

some_other_function () {
    touch some_other_file
}
```

and i want to call the function some_other_function from c-code.

I understand, that i could simply write a shell script like

```
#!/bin/sh

source userscript.sh
some_other_function
```

and execute it using system(), but i am looking for a more elegant and especially a more generic solution, that lets me execute arbitrarily named functions and maybe even lets me get/set variables.

Comment: c can't dynamically load interpreted code

Comment: c can `exec` an external program/shell, so `exec('sh yourscript.sh foo bar baz');`, basically, where `foo bar baz` become arguments to  your external script.

Comment: You can execute function by sourcing bash and then calling the function. for example `bash -c ". myfuncs.sh ; call_to_func arg1"`

Comment: `/bin/sh` isn't `bash` (well, technically it might be provided by `bash`, but it's not the same thing).

Comment: @Steve Cox: I am aware of that. I already solved the problem in a way, as stated in the question. But i do not want to supply a seperate shellscript for every function i am calling from the shellscript. I am just looking for a more elegant/generic way to do it.

Comment: You could `popen("bash", "w")` and write commands into it.

Comment: Any reason not to use `system("source userscript.sh; some_other_function");`? Setting variables in the shell is easy enough — build the string that sets them and pass it to the call to `system()`, noting that .  Getting variables is considerably harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this directly from C. However, you can use [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to run a command (like `sh`) from C:

```
// Run the command: sh -c 'source userscript.sh; some_other_function'
system("sh -c 'source userscript.sh; some_other_function'");
```

(Note that the `sh -c 'command'` lets you run `command` in a shell.)

Alternatively, you can also use [`execlp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) or some other function from the `exec` family:

```
// Run the command: sh -c 'source userscript.sh; some_other_function'
execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "source userscript.sh; some_other_function", NULL);
```

(Note here that when using `exec` functions, the first argument – `"sh"` – *must be repeated*)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I understand that you want to call one of several functions defined in your script. You can do this, if you give the function as an argument to the shell script and in the last line just have `$1`, e.g.

```
fun1()
{
    echo "fun1 called"
}

fun2()
{
    echo "fun2 called"
}

$1
```

You can then call your script as

```
sh userscript.sh fun1
```

which gives

> fun1 called

Comment: pretty sure this doesn't work, but could be wrong, but just tried with bash and you can not call / invoke a function in a bash script like this, at least i can't on my current box.

Comment: @ipatch It does work, just tried it myself. See example added.